# Migration IIS6 to IIS7 - Web Deploy Service Fails To Start

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

I am trying to migrate an entire server from IIS 6 to IIS 7. While there are only 10 web sites, some of them have fairly complex configurations that would be time consuming to do manually (although I have wasted so much time trying to use Web Deploy already, it is starting to look like the better option).

I tried following the instructions outlined in [Migrate a Web Site from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/427/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7/), but on the IIS 6 source server I am running sites that use host header names and the default port 80 conflicts with IIS. So I used the command line to install it on port 6222:

```
msiexec /i x86_msdeploy.msi /passive ADDLOCAL=ALL LISTENURL=http://+:6222/MSDEPLOY2/
```

The installation succeeds, however I run net start to start the service as outlined in the article and it fails to start.

```
net start msdepsvc
```

The error message was "The Web Deployment Agent Service service terminated with the following error: %%2148734208". I did some research and discovered someone else with the same error message and he said he rebooted the server to fix the issue.

Herein lies my problem: **the reason for migration is that the server will not recover from a reboot**. I tried rebooting and ended up having to restore the machine from backup in order to get it to boot again (and then of course, MSDeploy was completely gone from the server).

I did some more digging and discovered this [more complete MSDeploy article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627317.aspx), but the instructions also require the MSDeploy service to be running on the IIS 6 source server.

My questions are -

1. Is there a way to start the service without requiring a reboot?
2. If not, is there a standalone executable that can be used to export the IIS 6 settings without having to run a service?
3. Or is there at least a tool that can be used to import the old IIS 6 XML file format into IIS 7?
4. Is my only option here to copy the settings manually, and if so is there some kind of a cheat sheet to find where a setting is in IIS 7 based on where it is located in IIS 6?

**Update**

Due to the lack of response and other alternatives, I ended up migrating the settings manually. IIS 7 didn't require as much of a learning curve as I anticipated and all of the sites seem like they are working as good or better than before even though they are using legacy versions of .NET (2.0 and 3.5).